# Using Zephyr for Jira Cloud's ZAPI with .Net

Tags: c#, rest, jira

I've put together some my solution, and I'm finally able to get a response from Zephyr, but it is giving me a 404 response, when I know that it is available.  Is anyone else trying to use ZAPI to report test data?

The secret and access key comes from the Jira page that Zephyr adds.  The project key comes from Jira.  Here is my code and the response it gives me:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Jira.SDK.Domain;
using JWT;

namespace WebPortalUITests.Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Reporting
    {
        static string User = "My.User.Name";
        static string Password = "My.Password";
        static string jiraBaseUrl = "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/";
        static string zephyrBaseUrl = "https://prod-api.zephyr4jiracloud.com/connect";
        static string Secret = "P1oihENe5PLUS_THE_REST_OF_MY_SECRET";
        static string AccessKey = "amlyYTox_PLUS_THE_REST_OF_MY_KEY";

        public async Task<bool> CycleExists(string Name)
        {
            //connect to Jira to get project and version IDs using the Jira.SDK library
            Jira.SDK.Jira jira = new Jira.SDK.Jira();
            jira.Connect(jiraBaseUrl, User, Password);
            Project webPortal = jira.GetProject("WP");
            long id = webPortal.ID;
            long version = webPortal.ProjectVersions.Last<ProjectVersion>().ID;

            //format the Zephyr request and use it to generate a JWT
            string request = "/connect/public/rest/api/1.0/cycles/search?versionId=" + version + "&projectId=" + id;
            string finalAPI = zephyrBaseUrl + request;
            string token = JsonWebToken.Encode(finalAPI, Secret, JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);

            //put the JWT and the accesskeys in the header and request the info
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(zephyrBaseUrl)})
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "JWT "+token);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("zapiaccesskey", AccessKey);

                using (var response = httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format(request)).Result)
                {
                    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                }
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

- response    {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
  {
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2017 20:34:01 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 0
  }}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Comment: Smarty admins removed my answer which could help you a lot because contained working example, but I think you need to check it still: https://github.com/zephyrdeveloper/zapi_csharp/blob/master/ZapiCSharp/ZapiCSharp.cs

Comment: Thank you, Tony.  I changed jobs, but I'm sure it will help someone.